# stack using two queues in python

Tags: python, queue, stack

While implementing stack using two queues I get this error:
Code:

```
class Stacks():
    def __init__(self):
        self.q1=[]
        self.q2=[]
    def push(self,x):
        if len(self.q1)==0:
            self.q1.append(x)
            print("added")
        else:
            for i in range(len(self.q1)-1):
                self.q2.append(self.q1.pop(0))
            self.q1.append(x)
            for j in range(len(self.q2)-1):
                self.q1.append(self.q2.pop(0))

    def pop(self):
            return self.q1.pop(0)

s1=Stacks()
s1.push(1)
s1.push(2)
s1.push(3)
print(s1.pop())
print(s1.pop())
print(s1.pop())
```

> > While executing this code I get 2 3 and error(popping from empty list).But I should get 3 2 1 . What is the mistake?

Comment: Replace `range(len(self.q1)-1)` with `range(len(self.q1))` and same for the second loop. The current implementation misses the last element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Here, fixed it for you. The mistake was that you subtracted by 1 unnecessarily.

[image]

```
class Stacks():
    def __init__(self):
        self.q1=[]
        self.q2=[]
    def push(self,x):
        if len(self.q1)==0:
            self.q1.append(x)
        else:
            for i in range(len(self.q1)):
                self.q2.append(self.q1.pop(0))
            self.q1.append(x)
            for j in range(len(self.q2)):
                self.q1.append(self.q2.pop(0))
        print("added: "+str(x))

    def pop(self):
        return self.q1.pop(0)

s1=Stacks()
s1.push(1)
s1.push(2)
s1.push(3)
print("removed: "+str(s1.pop()))
print("removed: "+str(s1.pop()))
print("removed: "+str(s1.pop()))
```